# WSALookupServiceNext on BlueTooth, corrupted heap exception

Tags: c++, exception, bluetooth, winsock, heap-corruption

we'll get straight to business, the following snippet returns

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7786AA3C (ntdll.dll) in Project4.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x7787FE38).
```

Snippet:

```
while(true)
{
    if(WSALookupServiceNext(lookup_handle,flags,&query_set_length,query_set)==NO_ERROR)
    {
        char buffer[40] = {0};
        DWORD buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);

        device_socket_address = (SOCKADDR_BTH*)query_set->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr;
        result = device_socket_address->btAddr;


        WSAAddressToString(query_set->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH),NULL,buffer,&buffer_size);

        fprintf(stdout,"found device: %s - %s\n", buffer,query_set->lpszServiceInstanceName);
        break;

    }

}
```

The break occurs on `WSAAddressToString`

before WSALookupServiceNext I call

```
//start the LookUp service for bluetooth devices
if(WSALookupServiceBegin(query_set,flags,&lookup_handle)==SOCKET_ERROR)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "something went completely wrong... %d",WSAGetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    ExitProcess(2);
}
```

Query set initialization

```
DWORD query_set_length = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
DWORD flags = LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR;

WSAQUERYSET query_set = (WSAQUERYSET*)malloc(query_set_length);

ZeroMemory(query_set,query_set_length);


query_set->dwSize = query_set_length;
query_set->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
query_set->dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 0;
```

Update:
The source of the problem seems to be `WSALookupServiceNext`, I suspect my handle(lookup_handle) of being passed in a wrong manner.

- My question being, what caused the heap corruption, and how can i repair it?
- I just want to find a device, and be able to send it a test string.
- I also think it is worth mentioning that I already have a BlueTooth-enabled android device paired with my PC (not necessarily connected though).
- any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is the buffer you pass to `WSALookupServiceNext` or `WSAAddressToString` is not big enough and the heap is getting trashed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff519648(v=vs.85).aspx
This is the reason why my buffer is 40 chars long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed `LUP_FLUSCACHE` and `LUP_CONTAINERS` from my flags,

```
DWORD flags = LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR;
```

and only use it in `WSALookupServiceBegin`

```
if(WSALookupServiceBegin(query_set,flags |= LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_CONTAINERS,&lookup_handle)==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "something went completely wrong... %d",WSAGetLastError());
        system("PAUSE");
        ExitProcess(2);
    }
```

it seems to prevent the problem.
I just read this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

hehe, I also used fprintf to stdin instead of stdout (may I burn in eternal fire).